# Android. to display contacts as list view

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts, listactivity

I want to display contacts in list view and add actions on all contacts , like on click on a particular contact it should display the phone number , mail id and delete of the particular contact...

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CPDemo1 extends ListActivity {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     String str[]=    {"datta","vivek","Nagesh sir","shiv"};
     String name; 

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())


         do {

         int x = 0;

         name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
         str[x]= name;
                 x++;
          ArrayAdapter arr = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);

          setListAdapter(arr);
 } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
```

Comment: Whats holding you back from doing what you want?

Comment: @WarrenFaith ... i am trying to display the phone book contacts but i am unable to do so... in my code the name variable is overriding the hard core values by only one contact from phone book.. i want to display all contacts first in list view and then add actions on it.. just see where i am missing the loops to do that..

Answer (score 10):

The problem in your current code is create new adapter for every loop. Just move `ArrayAdapter arr = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);`
 out of `do while loop`. And another issue, You work too much on `UIThread` (loop through cursor )so user will see a black screen or ANR if your numbers of contact is huge. Learn to use `AsyncQueryHandler` and `CursorAdapter`, it's all in my link and nikki's link

And why don't you have a look at default Contacts app in Android source code:
Below is my custom Contacts App.[image]

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts

Comment: To downvoter, You should leave a reason why you downvote my answer. With a general question like this, don't expect a copy-paste running snippet. My answer help him on improving his provided code.

Answer (score 3):

Just have a look at below link and try using this code for displaying contacts saved in android phone book into your application.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little change to the code posted by you, it will solve your problem.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {

        int x = 0;
     do {



     name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
     Log.d("CONTENT",name);
     str[x]= name;
             x++;
      } while(cursor.moveToNext());

     ArrayAdapter<String> arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);

     setListAdapter(arr);
```