# Android creating a listview like native coantacts app

Tags: android, android-listview

I have been searching for over 3 days with no success for a class that will create a listview similar to the Android contacts list. I.e. a list with a alphabet indexing panel on the right side that animates too.

If anyone has done it successfully and can share, then I would really appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: You can check [my answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11628106/1050058) and [answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11921803/1050058)